# Компилировать EXE в MASM

Tags: ассемблер, exe, masm, dos

Изучал Assembler по Калашникову, но в его книге описано только как создавать .com (односегментные) программы.

Меня интересуют многосегментные .exe, нужно по некоторым причинам (64 Кб уже не хватает).

Интересует два вопроса:

1. Как оформлять сегменты. Если Калашников пишет

   ```
   CSEG segment
   assume ...
   org 100h
   ...
   CSEG ends
   ```

   То как оформлять exe? Подобным образом?
2. Какие ключи указывать MASM 6.11 для компиляции в exe? Без ключей он в .exe компилирует?
3. Что ещё надо знать?

Рысканья в тырнете результата не дали. Кругом "как скомпилить под форточки", или "как скомпилить .com", или "почему тут ошибка"... А если и находится вопрос "как скомпилить .exe в MASM", то речь идёт о MASM32 и кодах ошибок, но не про то, как оформлять исходник...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С учетом того, что нужно получить exe файл для dos:

1. Сегменты оформляются точно так же, но без `org 100h` - это специфика формата `com`. Пример hello world:

   ```
   CSEG segment
   assume CS:CSEG, DS:DSEG, SS:SSEG
   start:
       mov ax, DSEG
       mov ds, ax

       mov ah,9
       mov dx,offset Message
       int 21h

       mov ax, 4C00h
       int 21h
   CSEG ends

   DSEG segment
       Message db 'Hello, world$'
   DSEG ends

   SSEG segment stack
       db 256 dup (?)
   SSEG ends

   end start
   ```

   Имена сегментов (`CSEG`, `DSEG`, `SSEG`), меток (`start`) могут варьироваться.
2. Сборка в два этапа (для masm32):

   ```
   ml /c test.asm
   link16 test.obj,test.exe,nul,nul,nul
   ```

   Для masm 6 скорее всего `link` вместо `link16`. `nul` при линковке означает, что не нужно создавать map файл, не линкуем библиотеки, не используем def файл. Описание ключей - `ml /?`, `link16 /?`.
3. Гуглите именно книги с упоминанием masm, в книгах как правило более полный обзор материала. Книги по tasm с примерами под dos тоже подойдут - синтаксис tasm и masm более-менее совместим.